# Url Rewrite is not work in Visual 2013 Professional

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, visual-studio-2013

I have project which is working well **Url rewriting stuff** in **vs2012 Ultimate** but same project if I try to open in **VS 2013 professional** then url rewriting is not working.

Actually I didn't get any error at that time but when I click on any links it's shows me like
"The resource cannot be found."

and project take too much time to load index page in **VS 2013 Professional** compare to **VS 2012 ultimate**

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is this "Url rewriting" that is spoken of?

Comment: do you mind post the code so that it is easier to figure out what happen.

Comment: URL rewriting can be one of the best and quickest ways to improve the usability and search friendliness of your site. It can also be the source of near-unending misery and suffering.

Comment: code of rewriter as below in web.config

Comment: All code reside in web.config ( I have attached snap code) file there is no any external code.

Comment: Have you tried enabling Debug [logging](http://urlrewriter.net/index.php/support/reference/loggers/debug-logger)? The project is 3 years old, possibly there are some referenced assemblies that should be updated...

Comment: But that Same code is working fine in VS2012 Ultimate IDE. This code just creating href (URL)

Comment: So what? The fact that it worked earlier doesn't help a bit. You need to dig deeper (enable logging) to understand the reason.

Comment: I have enabled logging but not any luck yet.

Comment: Just a clarifying question: Are you talking about running the site via Visual Studio, as opposed to running it on the server? If so, are you using the VS Development Server or IIS Express? Check each version of Visual Studio to see; that may be part of the problem.

Comment: Well, let me try to explain from beginning
I have one project that I was opened it in VS 2012 Ultimate before and it's working well (url rewriting stuff) in both ways locally as well as with IIS but recently I have installed VS 2013 Professional version so somehow isn't going to work both the way.

Answer (score 0):

Your code have nothing with Visual studio 2012 or 2013. The code you are running will be work fine and exact same in both version.

Sometime you run the dll that is not compiled from current code. Our Visual studio sometime not build the build and use the build that we made last time (maybe current one have issue so VS use old compiled copy).

Did you have try to check Rebuild and clean. Try that thing maybe help you.

Better you can set URL_Rewriter in IIS on your server.

Comment: Yes. I have tried many times build/Rebuild and clean solution in VS 2013 Professional and even I have downloaded/installed "Microsoft URL Rewrite Module 2.0 for IIS 7 (x64)" from "http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=7435" and bind my application with IIS  but not any luck.

Comment: @Nimesh In past we have same trouble. We use .html extension after every url that is part of server side IIS settings. its write some code in web.config file as same as yours. I try to get it done in my PC for hours and in end when server administrator do that again through IIS it's work fine for me. I thing you have trouble same problem as I have in past.

Comment: So, what is solution ? Will you please suggest me ?